# max number from array in library

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a library for C#, that would get the maximum number in a listbox. 
Currently I am just trying the method in the program before creating the library. The following code is what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace SPE16
{
public partial class FormExamStatistics : Form
{
    List<double> ExamScores = new List<double>();
    double highScore = 0;

    public FormExamStatistics()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private double HighScore(List<double> anyList) //return the highest score
    {
        return highScore = ExamScores.Max();
    }
    private void buttonAddFromFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        StreamReader reader;
        reader = File.OpenText("ExamScores.txt");
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            double Scores;
            double.TryParse(reader.ReadLine(), out Scores);
            ExamScores.Add(Scores);
            listBoxScores.Items.Add(Scores);
            labelHighScore.Text = highScore.ToString();
        }
        reader.Close();
        /////////////
        HighScore(ExamScores);
        /////////////
    }
}
}
```

Now, it is supposed to return the maximum value from the list created on top, which is populated by a text file "ExamScores.txt". This text file contains 60 (double) scores with a maximum number of 120.
The maximum number, should be 120, but it returns "0".

Now I need to make this as a method first, in order to create a (dll) library later.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide good [MCVE]. It is very unclear why regular `Enumerable.Max` does not work for you. It may be good option to try it out (so far code shown does not demonstrate any calls to `.Max` as `HighScore` never called).

Comment: according the method name it seems to be used only to load the file, and to find the max ! maybe it's called later

Comment: Hey Thanks for replying.
I dont know much of programming, and so far I thought that by "return highScore ExamScores.Max();" I was creating the Maximum Value to return and almost by the bottom, I call it by sending it to a "labelHighScore.text = highScore.ToString();"
Or is that not the way to call it?

Comment: Alexei Levenkov you're right

Answer (score 0):

you need to check your file because.NET Framework design guidelines recommend using the Try methods. Avoiding exceptions is usually a good ide

```
if (value == null)
{
    return 0.0;
}
return double.Parse(value, NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, provider)
```

please post a your file content

did you tried,

```
private void buttonAddFromFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    StreamReader reader;
    reader = File.OpenText("ExamScores.txt");
     while (!reader.EndOfStream){
         double Scores;
         double.TryParse(reader.ReadLine(), out Scores);
         ExamScores.Add(Scores);
         listBoxScores.Items.Add(Scores);
         labelHighScore.Text = highScore.ToString();
     }
     reader.Close();
     /////////////
     HighScore(ExamScores);
     /////////////
    }
```

Comment: What is "your file content"? you mean the txt file? I dont know how to attach in a reply but, I can tell you, its a text file, that contains 60 (double numbers). They are stacked vertically, 1 record per line, where the minimum is around 48.5 and the maximum value is 120.
48.5
90.5
120
99.5
63
88
89
74.5
105
62.5
58.5
104.5
81
63
73.5
88
98.5
63.5
85.5
58
87
68
73
56
94.5
81.5
97.5
100.5
115.5
79.5
79
106.5
80.5
117.5
104
77
53
27
54.5
59.5
53
62
60.5

Comment: yep, just copy paste a part from your file

Comment: Cant make them look vertically as they are in the file, but these are all the records. 1 record per line, vertically.
48.5
90.5
120
99.5
63
88
89
74.5
105
62.5
58.5
104.5
81
63
73.5
88
98.5
63.5
85.5
58
87
68
73
56
94.5
81.5
97.5
100.5
115.5
79.5
79
106.5
80.5
117.5
104
77
53
27
54.5
59.5
53
62
60.5
65
90.5
103.5
89.5
74.5
84
101.5
98
62
59
57
91.5
45.5
51.5
70
96
107.5

Comment: the post amended

Comment: Changed it to "ExamScore" and the error is gone, but I still get a "0" in the maximum Score label.

Comment: Posted complete in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Proper sample for the question would be:

```
var highScore = 0;
labelHighScore.Text = highScore.ToString();
highScore = 42;
```

Written this way it clearly demonstrates that showing value first and only than changing it does not actually display updated value.

Fix: set value before showing it, likely `labelHighScore.Text = highScore.ToString();` should be just moved to the end of the function.

Note that there are likely other problems in the code based on strange way `HighScore` returns result and how code completely ignores result of the function.

Comment: I just noticed that, like 5 minutes before you commented. I changed the quantities in "highScore" at the top, and that quantity also changes in my label so, its not returning the method at all. I dont know what else to do. I have changed its location but its just not loading my method whatsoever. I will tinkle with it but, I dont have an idea of what else can I do.
Thanks Alexei.